# Camara de Android

Tags: android

Estoy desarrollando una app con opencv.....
Tengo un Sony Xperia XA2 Ultra, este dispositivo tiene 2 cámaras frontales.
he estado jugando con el código y solamente me deja acceder a la camara trasera y solo a una camara frontal,donde camara trasera es = 0 y camara frontal es = 1.

Cuando intento Cambiarle el parametro a

```
CameraBridgeViewBase.setCameraIndex(param);
```

y le ingreso un numero del 2 en adelante

me lanza el siguiente error:
[image: me lanza el siguiente error]

quisiera saber como acceder a la segunda cámara frontal o como pedir el permiso de la segunda cámara.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recuerda que es importante definir el siguiente permiso en tu AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
```

**Te sugiero obtener los ids de las camaras, probablemente estes tratando de usar un id incorrecto**, usa el método para obtener los id de las camaras:

```
private void getCameras(){

    Camera.CameraInfo cameraInfo = new Camera.CameraInfo();
    for (int i = 0; i < Camera.getNumberOfCameras(); i++) {
        Camera.getCameraInfo(i, cameraInfo);
        Log.i(TAG, "camera "+ i + " : " + cameraInfo.facing + " : "  );
        if (cameraInfo.facing == Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT) {

        }
    }
}
```

ahora llamalo e imprime los ids de las camaras dentro del dispositivo:

```
    String[] camaras = getCamerasCount();
    //Imprime ids
    for(String camara : camaras){
        System.out.println("Camara Id " + camara);
    }
```

Comment: Realiza tus preguntas con la mayor información posible, por ejemplo define que estas usando una librería.

Comment: el problema que actualmente se utiliza `android.hardware.camera2` porque `android.harware.camera` esta obsoleta

Comment: gracias ya me arrojo las camaras y solo detecta 2,la trasera y la frontal. ni modo